# Ambigous question regarding how to view surds with numbers infront

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

Say I want to multiply 2 by 5$\sqrt3$ . Do I firstly do 2 * 5, then 2 * 3? I'm not sure about the order of operations here. Such a dumb question, I know.

Edit - can someone show me the systematic way of rationalizing this:

$\frac{\sqrt5 + \sqrt2}{4\sqrt5 - 3\sqrt3}$

When I look at this, I think of the difference of two squares at the bottom, but I also think of multiplying by the conjuguate. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: You can't multiply "through a square root". Actually you can, but it's not what you think: $a\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a^2b}$ (if $a \geq 0$). So your answer is $10\sqrt{3}$. Or if you prefer, $\sqrt{300}$...

Comment: $5\sqrt 3=5 \times \sqrt 3$, now do $2\times 5 \times \sqrt3$

Comment: It's good to ask about such things to better understand general principles, but for quick sanity checks, I suggest also using an electronic calculator to help answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $a\sqrt b = a\cdot \sqrt b.\;$ Here, $5\sqrt 3 = 5\cdot \sqrt 3$. So multiplying by $2$ gives $$2\cdot 5\cdot \sqrt 3 = 10\cdot\sqrt 3 = 10\sqrt 3$$

Comment: Yes, to rationalize your fraction, multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the *denominator*.

Answer (score 1):

Using $a(bc)=(ab)c,$ we have $2\cdot 5 \sqrt{3}=10 \sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of the distribution rule: $2(5+\sqrt{3})$ then you multiply the 2 times the 5 and the 2 times the $\sqrt{3}$.  This is the not the case for $2\cdot5\sqrt{3}$.